# Does pulling email from gmail download the spam folder also?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, pop3

Does pulling email from gmail download the spam folder also?

I want to user mozzila's email client to backup my gmail emails.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about POP email, it will only download messages from your Gmail Inbox (and Sent Items).

Comment: Gmail POP retrieval will also download messages from the Gmail *Sent Mail* folder/label.

Comment: Good point. I don't use POP anymore, IMAP is so much better.

Comment: @THTG: Yep, and the web interface is better than both. ;)

Comment: That's also a good point. I only use IMAP on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you used IMAP instead, and enabled the Advanced IMAP in the Labs section then you could choose not to download the spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

for using Tbird with gmail, best to use these addons:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/6381
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/1339
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/7307
use all 3 for the full gmail experience in TTbird

also under settings in gmail, you can further play with imap settings, and there's a lab feature to let you customize it even more

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, **no** - Gmail will only download items in your inbox over POP. I personally have never seen it download items in your sent - but I never used the web interface to send email, so all my sent items would be in my sent items folder.